# Why doesn't MASM work on Mac OS X?

Tags: assembly, x86, operating-system, hardware, cpu-architecture

I am currently taking a class on Assembly Language and Computer Architecture. We're programming in MASM for x86 processors. I have a Macbook Air, so of course I have to run Windows on a virtual machine to program in MASM for our assignments.

What I'm confused about: We're learning about, and programming for x86 architecture. When I looked up my Macbook Air's processor, it seemed to be in the x86 family. Considering that, why doesn't MASM work with Mac OS X?

Furthermore, if assembly language communicates directly w/ hardware, why does merely installing the Windows OS (or running it through a VM) on Apple Hardware suddenly allow me to program in MASM?

Thanks,
Ian

[EDIT for clarification: My understanding -- please tell me if i'm wrong -- is that Assembly Language is as "low as you can go." I.e. it's pre-operating system, and provides instructions directly to the hardware itself. Thus, I don't understand why an assembly language for x86 architecture doesn't work on ALL x86 machines, regardless of OS]

Comment: MASM is Microsoft. Mac OS X is Apple. Microsoft and Apple don't like each other.

Comment: Why should it? Xcode has its own assembler.

Comment: @Mysticial They're secret lovers.

Comment: Maybe, like R&J, they'll both end up dead.

Comment: @Seva: Xcode uses the GNU assembler, which uses a different (and, IMO, terribly ugly and illegible) syntax, AT&T style. But Jester's answer explains why MASM won't work. Anyway, perhaps on the Mac, NASM or FASM can be used. They are much more similar to MASM than GASM.

Comment: Not strictly true - Xcode has used clang for a good few years now.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Programs are made up of more than just the raw machine code. The executable needs to have a special format that the OS can understand, so it can load and run the code. Also, the code expects a certain environment, such as libraries and system calls (along with the appropriate calling conventions).

To compile and run your assembly program you need to assemble it first, that is run it through MASM in this case. However, MASM itself is a windows executable. It is in the executable format for windows, and it uses libraries and operating system functions accordingly. As such, you can't run it directly on mac os. Afterwards, you typically also need to link your code, which has the same issues. The next problem is with the program itself. MASM (and the rest of the toolchain) is by default also targeting windows (or dos) and so the created program has the appropriate format.

You can theoretically create a program intended to run on mac os using windows and masm. This is called cross-compiling in general. If your toolchain does not support the required mac format, you will need to create everything by hand. You obviously also need to write your program such that it expects the mac environment. For example, you can't use dos interrupts or windows libraries.

Since the architecture is the same, you don't need to virtualize the cpu. You can get away with emulating just the environment. An example for this is the windows emulator, `wine`, or `cygwin` emulating unix on windows.

A very rough analogy: there are human languages that use the same alphabet, but you still need to translate. There are also languages that do not even use the same alphabet, or don't even have letters. You will need to do more work in these cases.

Comment: Very good explanation, more or less what I would have written. +1

Comment: cygwin is immitation, not emulation